# Populating a PDF with Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, templates, pdf

I am currently developing an App for OSX which performs multiple actions, and should offer an option to export some data as a PDF.

The generated PDF should have a complex style: some vector elements with borders and backgrounds, an optional image, custom font types, and maybe some paragraph formatting.

I have experience on controlling Adobe InDesign from an App to inject data into a template, and export a PDF file, but in this case I need to embed all the functionality in my App, so my client doesn't need anything else.

I need a way to have some kind of templates, in which I can inject data from the App, with the possibility of repeating design elements of the template. Imagine an Invoice , it has some fields that need to be populated once, like the client name and address; but there are other elements that need to be repeated for each product listed in the invoice.

I've been doing research on the subject and I've found some info on Cocoa Drawing and Quartz, but that would require to code the templates inside my App, and it'd be nice to have them separately, as importable data for the App. (That's because I'm also a designer and I'd like to offer custom template designs for the users of my App).

Perhaps one approach could be using HTML/CSS render (in the app or remotely) and convert that into a PDF? I could do that conversion inside the App or with PHP... Would this two options keep the elements vectorial? That's not crucial, it's only a matter of file size.

Is there any way / Cocoa library to get this working in a similar way of what I have in mind? I'm not a very experienced programmer in Cocoa, in fact I'm quite new to it, but I've done many things in lots of other OOP languages.

Sorry about the long question, I just wanted to be clear with my project.

Thank you!

Comment: I think your choices are to use NSView / NSTableView, or something which renders in a web view. I'm not aware of any template-based report libraries for Cocoa, though I've seen some commercial tools like that for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate reasonably complex template driven PDFs in a Cocoa app using the PDFPageBuilder framework. There is a decent demo app included that indicates the range of features supported.

Text can be accurately positioned and the styling options include font name, size, colour and paragraph justification. Images can also be inserted.

There is also support for enumerating objects and simple boolean conditional expressions.

https://github.com/ThesaurusSoftware/PDFPageBuilder